# Update Firebird table with data from csv Python

Tags: python, sql, csv, firebird

Let's say we have a CSV file with payment information like this:

```
somthing1:500.00
somthing2:300.00
somthing3:200.00
```

I need to update different rows in a `tableB` in a Firebird database that has a column called `paid` with the values in the second column in the CSV file. For that reason iI created a *global temporary table* just to pump the data in it and then to update the desired table. What I tried is this:

```
idd = 0
with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as file:
    reader = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=':'))
    for row in reader:
        idd += 1
            c.execute("""INSERT INTO temp_table (id,code,paid) VALUES (?,?,?)""", 
            (idd,str(row[0]),str(row[1]), ))
```

This works as expected - the table is populated. After that I tried to update other table like this:

```
c.execute("""select paid from temp_table;""")
res = c.fetchall()
for r in res:
    c.execute(f"""UPDATE tableB SET paid = {r[0]} WHERE oid = 10;""")
```

This does work - for every result from the `SELECT` query it updates all of the rows with the same value of the next result from that. I tried with `MERGE` in the database itself with the same result - every row is updated with the same value from `temp_table`:

```
MERGE INTO tableB b
USING (SELECT paid FROM temp_table) e
ON b.paid = 0 AND oid = 10
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET b.paid = e.paid;
```

I need some way to update first row from `tableB` with first row from the CSV and so on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not correlating rows from the `temp_table` with rows in the `tableB`.

In your initial attempt, you update all rows in `tableB` with `oid = 10`. Similarly, in your second attempt you update all rows with `paid = 0` without correlating to `temp_table`.

You need add a condition to match rows between the tables, say both have an `id` column:

```sql
MERGE INTO tableB b
USING (SELECT paid FROM temp_table) e
ON b.paid = 0 AND b.oid = 10 AND b.id = e.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET b.paid = e.paid;
```

Comment: Will this work if the id columns are not equal i.e `b.id = 10 , e.id = 5`?

Comment: @T0ny1234 For each row in `tableB1`, there must be a way to correlate that row in `tableB` to at most one row in `temp_table` (Firebird actually allows you to match a single row to multiple rows, and might therefor update multiple times, but that should be considered a bug). Whether that is by ID (which was just my example), or an entirely different condition, that I can't know because you haven't provided sufficient information in your question to make that determination.

Comment: Thank you again. What you said is exactly what I was afraid is the reason behind all of this. For me to get the needed info I have to make a `JOIN` with another table in the `SELECT` condition.

Comment: @T0ny1234 Adding a join should be simple though, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you.